# Okhttp post json array

Tags: android, json, okhttp

I am trying to do a post.

```
        RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("userId", userId)
            .add("patientName", patient.getName())
            .add("patientDob", patient.getDOB())
            .add("referralFor", patient.getFor())
            .add("patientPhoto", "")
            .add("message", "test")
            .add("referralParticipants", )
            .build();
```

however the referralParticipants is a json Array. Which also could be dynamic. I am unsure how to do this, as there is nothing in form data, it seems to just be raw json being sent??

[image]

Answer (score 8):

This is how you are supposed to create `RequestBody` for media type `application/json`:

declare `application/json` media type:

```
public static final MediaType JSON
      = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

Create `request` object:

```
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, jsonStringToBePosted);
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                      .url(url)
                      .post(body)
                      .build();
```